# Grails Spring Security Core Create New User

Tags: authentication, grails, spring-security, grails-plugin

Installed the latest spring-security-core plugin for grails 2.1.0, launched s2-quickstart com.myapp User Role, it create User Role and UserRole domain, then generate-all com.myapp.User and com.myapp.Role to build basic CRUD. Now i'm trying to create a "Register" button to allow new users to sign in, using the User create() method, the problem is that when creating a new User, this one comes without Role, i'm trying to auto-assignate 'ROLE_USER' to every new user that register through the 'register' button and form.

Any help or suggestion is most welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in the controller action after checking that the user creation was successful:

```
def roleUser = Role.findByName('ROLE_USER')
UserRole.create user, roleUser, true
```

Comment: At the moment, i'm providing registration through the default create method from User controller by a view.gps, using 
<g:createLink controller="user" action="create">
So how and where to catch the user creation and where should i had the new UserRole?

Comment: Sounds like you're using dynamic scaffolding - switch to static (use the `generate-controller` or `generate-all` scripts) and edit the `create` controller action.

Comment: Note, I had to use`Role.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER')` rather than `Role.findByName('ROLE_USER')`

Answer (score 5):

I've been doing something like this in one of my apps. I've used

> generate-all mypackage.User

User was class which extends SecUser (domain object created by Spring Security Core).
I add this code to UserController:

```
def springSecurityService // injection of Spring Security

def create() {
    def user = springSecurityService.getPrincipal() 
    [userInstance: new User(params)]
}

def save() {
    def map=params
    def userInstance = new User(params)
    if (!userInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [userInstance: userInstance])
        return
    }

    if (!userInstance.authorities.contains(SecRole.findByAuthority(params.role))) {
        SecUserSecRole.create userInstance, SecRole.findByAuthority(params.role)
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'user.label', default: 'User'), userInstance.id])
    redirect(action: "show", id: userInstance.id)
}
```

In BootStrap class I've made some roles:

```
def springSecurityService

def init = { servletContext ->

    def userRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(failOnError: true)
    def adminRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_ADMIN') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(failOnError: true)
    def moderatorRole = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_MODERATOR') ?: new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_MODERATOR').save(failOnError: true)
}
```

In user/_form.gsp template I've added this select to select role and send it in **params**

```
<sec:ifAllGranted roles="ROLE_ADMIN">
<g:select name="role" from="${['ROLE_USER', 'ROLE_MODERATOR', 'ROLE_ADMIN']}" value='ROLE_MODERATOR'/>
</sec:ifAllGranted>

<sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
<div class="hidden"><g:textField name="role" value="ROLE_USER"/></div>
</sec:ifNotLoggedIn>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code: 
Add this in the controller action after checking that the user creation was successful:

```
def userr = user.save flush:true

UserRole.create userr, roleUser.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER'), true
```