# Spring Security Why can't a newly created user view a secured page?

Tags: grails, spring-security

Using grails 2.4.3 and Spring Security RC4. Except for the users created in BootStrap.groovy, any other users (those created through the browser), can't access a specified controller. I have the following controller to be accessed:

```
package org.example
import grails.plugin.springsecurity.annotation.Secured

class SecureController {

    @Secured(['ROLE_USER'])
    def index() {
        render 'hello'
    }
}
```

In BootStrap:

```
def adminRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_ADMIN').save(flush: true)
def userRole = new SecRole(authority: 'ROLE_USER').save(flush: true)

def testUser = new SecUser(username: 'me', password: 'password')
testUser.save(flush: true)

SecUserSecRole.create testUser, adminRole, true

def teUser = new SecUser(username: 'me2', password: '123')
teUser.save(flush: true)
SecUserSecRole.create teUser, userRole, true
```

And my Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.userDomainClassName = 'org.example.SecUser'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.userLookup.authorityJoinClassName = 'org.example.SecUserSecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.authority.className = 'org.example.SecRole'
grails.plugin.springsecurity.logout.postOnly = false
grails.plugin.springsecurity.controllerAnnotations.staticRules = [
    '/':                              ['permitAll'],
    '/**':                            ['permitAll']
```

I have used the generate-all command on my SecUser to create new users in runtime.. but all the users created can't access the SecureController and I get: "Sorry, you're not authorized to view this page."
Any ideeas?

Comment: Hi Vantalk. Did you attach the SecRole 'userRole' to the user created in runtime ?

Comment: @Abincepto Creating the user in runtime asks only for username, password and the booleans: enabled, accountExpired, accountLocked and PasswordExpired. How can I add the userRole? (I thought that maybe the default role for any newly created is ROLE_USER)

Comment: There are no default roles. You have to create and assign them. The plugin and Spring Security don't care what they are, except that they must start with 'ROLE_' so the voters know what to do. There's nothing special about ROLE_USER other than what meaning you give it in your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my answer based on your comment (I had the same kind of issue two weeks ago, may be your situation is the same).

As you can see in your Bootstrap, it takes two steps to create a user and attach a role:

First, the creation of a new user:

```
def testUser = new SecUser(username: 'me', password: 'password')
```

Second, attach a role to a user:

```
SecUserSecRole.create teUser, userRole, true
```

There is no "default role" added. After the creation of the user, you probably need to add something like that:

```
def role = SecRole.findByAuthority('ROLE_USER')
SecUserSecRole.create user, role, true
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This answer was correct.. More exact was actually an answer from Burt here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11689776/grails-spring-security-core-create-new-user?rq=1. Can mark this as duplicate

Answer (score 2):

If the user exists and has the correct assigned roles, that doesn't automatically make the instance the logged-in user. They need to go to the login page and authenticate. If you want you can auto-authenticate them after persisting the domain class instances as long as you're confident that the data is consistent and a proper authentication would succeed. Use the `reauthenticate` method in `springSecurityService` for that.

This is intended to be used in scenarios where a logged-in user changes something that's cached in the `Authentication` instance that Spring Security stores in a `ThreadLocal` to keep track of their data during the request (e.g. roles, username, and anything extra you cache their like their real name, etc.) For example if you grant a new role, you would want to update the roles list that Spring Security uses so they can access the newly accessible pages for this request and all other requests until they authenticate again. By forcing in a new `Authentication` you do that, and later when they log in again, you'll read all the data from the database including these changes and end up with the same data. So you can take advantage of that convenient method for this case also to auto-authenticate the current user.

As convenient as auto-authentication is (and I do often think it seems a bit silly to have to re-enter the username and password I just registered at a site) it's safer to make them explicitly login. If anything was off and their subsequent logins will fail, you want that to happen as soon as possible.

Comment: I have a Login and Logout Controller available. I always logout after any other loghin (it works) and I always am prompted for Login when not loged and trying to acces my secured page. I understand that this is not enough?

Comment: No, that should work. Check out http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2003 and http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2029 - there should be something there that will point you at the real issue.